# Typescript issue after updating to create-react-app 4.0.0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have just updated `create-react-app` to `4.0.0` and I have encountered many issues. The first one was

`TypeError: Cannot add property noFallthroughCasesInSwitch, object is not extensible`

I solved it by adding `"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,` to my `tsconfig.json`

Now I'm able to start the app, but everything went just wrong. I have millions of apparently unsued variables, even though they are not.

[image]

I have updated `typescript` to `4.0.5` but the problem remains.

Also, my machine becomes very loud when I hit `yarn start`

Comment: Are you using prettier or some kind of linter like eslint? Can you show your `package.json`

Comment: did you cleared your cache when updated create-react-app some old cache package conflict sometimes after updates

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same for all types/interfaces imported.

Comment: @curly_brackets Unfortunately no, we gave up on it for now, we reversed the upgrade.

Comment: i have this same issue after upgrading react-scripts v4 in one of our workspaces. not sure how to fix and don't really want to turn the rule off.

Answer (score 3):

you can temporarily turn off eslint error **no-unused-vars** and **@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars** in file **.eslintrc**.
For example

```js
{
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "./node_modules/react-redux-typescript-scripts/eslint.js"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "camelcase": "off",
    "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off"
  }
}
```